# HTML escape for euro character not being interpreted in textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, euro

It's showing `&euro;` instead of the € (currency sign) in the textarea. Does anyone have an idea why this is going wrong?

```
<?php
$currency = "&euro;"; //using php with other data from database

echo "<script>
      $('#share_button').click(function(e){
      // pass the currency to javascript and put in textarea shared with other on clicks
           $('#snsdescp').val(`".$currency."`);
      });</script>";
?>

 //shared textarea
<textarea class="form-control" name="message" id="snsdescp"></textarea>
```

Comment: The `.val()` method doesn't set html, so `"&euro;"` isn't treated as an html entity, it's just treated as a plain string. You could use a "hack" like `.val($("<div>").html("&euro;").text())` to get the actual Euro character.

Comment: Because you are adding that as a value inside a `textarea`, not as HTML that would be parsed.

Comment: [html_entity_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) could help, server side

Comment: don't need to hack it, use `html()` instead of `val()`. Like `$('#snsdescp').html('&euro;');`

Comment: Just use the actual euro character `€`. Make sure the file is saved as UTF-8, served as UTF-8, and the HTML meta charset is set to UTF-8.

Comment: Don't show PHP, show JS/HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `val()` method does no encoding/decoding, as a *hack* you can use the `html()` function for the encoding and then strip the text:

```
$('#share_button').click(function(e){
    $('#snsdescp').val($("<div>").html("&euro;").text());
});
```

[Here is a working jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jbc5krbv/3/) for your textarea.

Comment: That's probably not going to work very well if the text contains characters such as `<` which you want to interpret as themselves, not HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can set it by assigning `&euro;` to the `innerHTML` property of the `textarea` element:

```
document.querySelector('#snsdescp').innerHTML = '&euro;';
```

If you would like to use jQuery, you can simply call its `.html()` method:

```
$('#snsdescp').html('&euro;');
```

Comment: A textarea has no `innerHTML` property.

Comment: Good point. In that case Chrome seems to try to do the right thing even though it is not supported cross platform.

Answer (score 0):

Well I am not getting why you storing in php variable, but probably you can store in javascript variable. It can help you out.

```
<?php
  $currency = "\u20ac"; //using php with other data from database
?>

 <textarea class="form-control" name="message" id="snsdescp"></textarea> 
  <br/><br/>
  <div id="share_button" >hello</div>//suppose your id is here

 <script>
    var value ="<?php echo $currency;?>"; //store php value in js variable
    $("#share_button").click(function(){

        $("#snsdescp").val(value);

     });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Unicode for € \u20AC

`$('#snsdescp').val("\u20AC");`